# JQgrid Virtual Scrolling not loading new rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, scroll

i am trying to modify my jqgrid table adding the virtual scrolling functionality. I can't find the reason of my problem: i scroll to the bottom and the new rows doesn't came out.
Here's my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var page;
    $("#visual").click(function()
    {
        $("#list").jqGrid(
        {
            url:'PrendiTutto',
            datatype: "json",
            height: 400,
            width:600,
            colNames:['id','model','cc','nation','prod'],
            colModel:[
                      {name:'id', index:'id', jsonmap:"id", width:25},
                      {name:'model', index:'model', jsonmap:"model", width:50},
                      {name:'cc', index:'cc', jsonmap:"cc", width:25},
                      {name:'nation', index:'nation', jsonmap:"nation", width:50},
                      {name:'prod', index:'prod', jsonmap:"prod", width:50}
                     ],
            rowNum: 40,
            rowTotal: 2000,
            rowList: [20,30,50],
            scrollrows: false,
            hoverrows: false,
            scroll: 10,
            pager: false,
            loadonce: true,
            mtype: 'GET',
            rownumbers: true,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            gridview: true,
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'id',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption: "Elenco delle Moto",
            jsonReader: {root: 'rows',page: 'page',total: 'total',records: 'records',repeatitems: false,id: 'id'},
        });
        $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{del:false,add:false,edit:false},{},{},{},{multipleSearch:true});
        $("#visual").fadeOut();
        $("#next").fadeIn();
        $("#add").fadeIn();
        $("#remove").fadeIn();
        page = $("#list").getGridParam("page");
    });
    $("#next").click(function()
        {
            page = $("#list").getGridParam("page");
            total = $("#list").getGridParam("lastpage");
            if(total != page)
                {
                    page ++;
                    $("#list").setGridParam({page:page}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                    $("#prev").fadeIn();
                }
            if((total) <= page)
                $("#next").fadeOut();
        });
    $("#add").click(function()
            {
                row = $("#list").getGridParam("rowNum");
                if(8 > row)
                    {
                        row++;
                        $("#list").setGridParam({rowNum:row}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                    }
            });
    $("#remove").click(function()
            {
                row = $("#list").getGridParam("rowNum");
                if(row > 1)
                    {
                        row--;
                        $("#list").setGridParam({rowNum:row}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                    }
            });
    $("#prev").click(function()
        {
            page = $("#list").getGridParam("page");
            if(page > 1)
                {
                    page --;
                    $("#list").setGridParam({page:page}).trigger("reloadGrid");
                    $("#next").fadeIn();
                }
            if(page <= 1)
                $("#prev").fadeOut();
        });
});
```

and the servlet that read's the data from the db:

```
public class PrendiTutto extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public PrendiTutto()
    {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.setContentType("text/json");
        MotoBeanManager moma = new MotoBeanManager();
        Collection<MotoBean> m = moma.loadMotos();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        int page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
        int row = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rows"));
        int j = 0, k = 0;
        int pagine = m.size()/row;
        if((m.size()%row) != 0)
        pagine++;
        String json = "{\"total\": \"" + pagine + "\",\"page\":\"" + page + "\",\"records\" :\"" + m.size() + "\", \"rows\":";
        json += "[";
        for(Iterator<MotoBean> i = m.iterator(); i.hasNext(); j++)
        {
            MotoBean moto = i.next();
            if((j < page*row)&&(j >= (page - 1)*row))
            {
                k++;
                json += "{";
                json += "\"id\": \"" + moto.getId() + "\",";
                json += "\"model\": \"" + moto.getModel() + "\",";
                json += "\"cc\": \"" + moto.getCc() + "\",";
                json += "\"nation\": \"" + moto.getNation() + "\",";
                json += "\"prod\": \"" + moto.getProd() + "\"";
                json += "}";
                if((k != row)&&(i.hasNext()))
                    json += ",";
            }
        }   
        json += "]}";
        out.print(json);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        doGet(request,response);
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are there any errors? Do you see an Ajax call going out? Did you look at the response from the server, does it look right?

Comment: There are no errors, i can see the ajax call when i initialize the table and all goes well. The problem is that when i scroll down the table nothing happens, no calls, no errors, nothing is like scrolling a simple table. Maybe can help the fact that i can read at the bottom of the table "View 1 - 40 of 40" instead of "View 1-40 of 11000" that i expected

Comment: Dunno what i've done.. same code but now it's running.. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
loadonce: true
```

that should be:

```
 loadonce: false
```